# Open and close the webpage using perl

Tags: perl, html

I would like to write the scripts to auto help me book a time slot in a website. Since i want to book like Monday to Friday, the scripts i write will pop up five tab in the browser by `system("start $book")` can i close the tab after i done the booking? Below is my example code.

```
use Time::Local;
use POSIX;


####### this week ##########

my $today = time ();
my $seconds = 24*60*60;
my @gmtime = gmtime ();
my@thisweek;
$today = $today - $gmtime[6] * $seconds;
for my $haha (0..4) {
    $today += $seconds;
    my @wday = gmtime ($today);
    push @thisweek,strftime ("%Y%m%d %Y%U", @wday);
}

($monday_1,$tuesday_1,$wednesday_1,$thursday_1,$friday_1) = @thisweek; 

book_time($monday_1,"1617");
book_time($tuesday_1,"1617");
book_time($wednesday_1,"1617");
book_time($thursday_1,"1617");
book_time($friday_1,"1617");

sub book_time()
{
my ($bookdate,$bookweek)= split " ",shift;
my $booktime= shift;
my $book = "http://www.example.com";
system("start $book");
}
```

Comment: why not use [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1712/lib/Win32/OLE.pm) then you could just quit when done?

Comment: Hi @GerhardBarnard, i am new in perl and not sure how to use this `Win32::OLE` in my scripts, can you show me an example? Thanks

Comment: see a simple demo in the below answer. You can find more help on the [Win::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1712/lib/Win32/OLE.pm) page

Comment: Look at WWW::Mechanize::Firefox and WWW::Mechanize::Chrome. With those, you can easily build the whole booking process automatically.

Comment: Or [Selenium::Remote::Driver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Selenium%3A%3ARemote%3A%3ADriver) if you actually want to control a web browser from your script.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1712/lib/Win32/OLE.pm) you manipulate the application itself.

An example of how to use this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE

my $my_page = Win32::OLE->new("InternetExplorer.Application"); # sets the app to open (IE)
   $my_page->{visible} = 1;    # sets whether the action is visible
   $my_page->Navigate("http://www.example.com"); # opens the page
   # ..do something while page is open...
   $my_page->Quit(); # close the page when done.
```

Obviously you would need to install the `Win32::OLE` module if you do not have it, by running `cpan install Win32::OLE` from cmd.

Comment: Hi, I has try the code above but this time is pop up a new IE window and the window is not closing.

Comment: Can you try now again?

Comment: yes, i try other website it work but since the website i want to reach is in .cgi format , so i think is the problem of the website i want to reach. Thanks

Comment: Hint.. cgi is perl, perhaps look at alternative get requests?

Comment: Which alternative get request can be use?

Comment: I think this works just for IE. And this is just not good enough! Work with Selenium seems to be a better solution because it is supported accross various platforms. You can try CasperJS to emule a browser. It's more "friendly" than Selenium and everything stays in Javascript(that I consider an advantage).